# Reduce HTML(style)/CSS code (background-size:... in background:...)

Tags: html, css

I need help reducing the `background-size` code to be inside the `background` property.

Code:

```
<html style="background:black url('http://example.com/image.jpeg')center no-repeat;background-size:auto 125%;cursor:none">
```

My attempt:

```
<html style="background:black url('http://example.com/image.jpeg')center auto 125% no-repeat;cursor:none">
```

Any other way to reduce the code will be appreciated. Also, no need to tell me about the < /html>.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/

The guide to background size.

Comment: what exactly does not work? you are not telling us what the issue is.

Comment: There is already an answer for this, it involes using a `/`. Should research better.

Comment: Why do you need to reduce the code?

Answer (score 2):

The official W3C spec for the `background` shorthand property is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background

The size property is written in the shorthand after the background-position and a forward slash. Example:

```
p { background: url("chess.png") 40% / 10em gray round fixed border-box; }
```

Is equivalent to:

```
p {
  background-color: gray;
  background-position: 40% 50%;
  background-size: 10em 10em;
  background-repeat: round;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url(chess.png) }
```